# For REST API development as per specific consumer structure

Tags: java, rest, api, structure

I have my application in Java having one central part having processing logic and number of nodes from which the central part if fetching the data.

Currently both central part and nodes both are in java and there are interfaces (having data fetching methods) that needs to be implemented by nodes which allows central part to fetch the data from node.

Now I want to externalise the node development so that it can be developed in any language and data can be fetched over HTTP. I am thinking of using REST API for the same. My nodes exposes as rest API and central part fetch data using the REST API calls.

My question here is  - Is it possible to define structure of REST API as per required by my central part that can be forced while developing the REST API.
For example, when I am implementing any interface in my java class of node It forces me to implement set of methods with specified parameters.
Is there any mechanism available by which I can force similar way to REST API development to have specific structure of rest API and parameters. Or some structure I can export and give to the REST developer against which they can validate their REST API.

Comment: I had a similar problems a year ago, in which data is gathered from each node. We solved it using apache thrift and zookeeper. So we used RPC in place of rest calls

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no language independent way to enforce others to code the REST-API as you want it in a way interfaces do. You will need a nice specification, that others can follow and you could derive test cases. So make a little tool, which takes the url of the rest-api to test and fetches data, validates it against what you expect and create a log-file with the results. you could then give this little tool to the other devs to test it.

It's not much, but perhaps this idea helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a REST service that consumes a JSON structure (i.e as the body of a POST method). To build a java client use POJO models that can be serialized to this JSON.

For example:

```
HttpEntity<RequestBean> request = new HttpEntity<RequestBean>(requestBean, headers);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());           
ResponseBean response = restTemplate.postForObject(endpoint, request, ResponseBean.class);
```

Where RequestBean is a Class which attributes are serialized as the expected JSON, and the one that you must provide to the REST developers.